# Determinant of anti-circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, circulant-matrices

> Find the determinant of the following matrix in the terms of $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ explicitly.
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n\\
> a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & \cdots & a_1\\
> a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & \cdots & a_2\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
> a_n & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1}\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$ When is the determinant zero?

Comment: @egreg: when I read the answer (and before reading your comment...) I suddenly thought of a community wiki, why not(?)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81016/determinant-of-a-specific-circulant-matrix-a-n/1164329#1164329

Comment: We should remark that the matrix in question is not a circulant matrix, but an *anti-circulant* matrix. So, its determinant is $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$ (or $(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$) times the determinant of its circulant counterpart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call that matrix $A$ and notice that it is a permutation of a circulant matrix,
$$
A = CP
$$
Where $P$ is a permutation matrix with ones on the anti-diagonal, and zeros in all other positions. Then

$$
\det[A] = \det[CP] = \det[C]\det[P]
$$
The determinant of the permutation part can be shown to depend on the size $n$. It can be written as
$$
\det[P] = (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}
$$
Now $C$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n} & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \cdots & a_1\\
a_{1} & a_{n} & a_{n-1} & \cdots & a_2\\
a_{2} & a_{1} & a_n & \cdots & a_3\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & a_{n-3} & \cdots & a_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$C$ is a circulant matrix. Define the associated polynomial
$$
f(\omega) = a_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\omega^k
$$
Then using the product formula on the Wikipedia page for circulant matrices, 
$$
\det[C] = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1}f(\omega_j),
$$
where $\omega_j=e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then the final formula is
$$
\det[A] = (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(a_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\omega_j^k\right)
$$

Comment: $A$ is circular already and don't needed to use matrix $C$!

Comment: $A$ is already a circulant? I don't believe so. The circulant marix form should at least have the same number on the main diagonal. $A$ does not have this property. Am I missing something?

Comment: @k1.M you might want to check out the definition on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @k1.M as an alternative perspective, you can see the circulant matrices in $M_n(\Bbb K)$ as the subalgebra generated by the special circulant matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ I_{n-1} & 0\end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: Strange to see activity on this thread after so long, but I'm glad there are more eyes on the solution above. I never got any feedback from the original poster, positive or negative, other than his or her misunderstanding about  the structure of circulant matrices.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is just the extension of the above *rajb245's answer*.

To answer more accurately also for the question "When the determinant is zero?"
it's sufficient to quote [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Rank)

Let the polynomial $ f(x) = a_n + a_1 x + \dots + a_{n-1} x^{n-1}  $ be so called the ''associated polynomial'' of circulant matrix  $C$.  Matrix $C$ is defined as in the above *rajb245's answer*.

The  rank   of circulant matrix $ C $ is equal to $ n - d $, where $ d  $ is the  degree of a polynomial degree  of  $\gcd( f(x), x^n - 1)  $.

So the determinant is equal to  zero when $f(x)$ and $x^n-1$ **have some common divisors**.

This property can be used for constructing a circulant matrix which would be at the same time singular  using fact that   $x^n-1$ has real root $ \{1 \}$ for odd $n$ and $ \{ -1, +1 \}$ real roots for even $n$.

For example let $n=4$.
Then we have general form of associated polynomial for root $-1$.

$f(x)=(x+1)(b_3+b_1x+b_2x^2)= \\ b_3+(b_1+b_3)x+(b_2+b_1)x^2+b_2x^3 = \\ a_4 + a_1 x +    a_2 x^2+ a_3 x^3 $

Take for example
  $f(x) = 6+7x+3x^2+2x^3$.

Indeed $\det{\begin{bmatrix}
 6 &   2 &  3 &  7 \\ 
7 &  6 &  2 &  3 \\
 3  & 7 &  6 &  2 \\
 2 &  3  & 7 &  6 
\end{bmatrix}}=0$ (circulant matrix)

Also for corresponding anticirculant matrix   (of the form as  in the question)

$\det{\begin{bmatrix}
 7 &   3 &  2 &  6 \\ 
3 &  2 &  6 &  7 \\
 2  & 6 &  7 &  3 \\
 6 &  7  & 3 &  2
\end{bmatrix}}=0$.