# DETERMINANT of matrix $M_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M_n=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    n-1 & n-2 & n-3 & ... & 1& 0\\
    n-2 & n-3 & n-4 & ... & 0& 1\\
    n-3 & n-4 & n-5 & ... & 1&2\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    1& 0 & 1 &...& n-3 & n-2\\
 0 & 1 & 2 &... & n-2&n-1
  \end{bmatrix}$

What's $\det(M_n)$ ?

Can someone help me with this, I tried Using Laplace's formula and transformations of rows but it didn't work.
[original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzhaC.jpg)

Comment: Looks like a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770117/determinant-of-circulant-matrix.

Comment: @MartinR Not sure. In this case $a_{11}=a_1=n-1$, while $a_{n2}=1\neq a_{11}$. Nevertheless, it may be a OP's typo. We will see...

Comment: @m2017m Please see MartinR's comment and check your formula. There might be a typo in you second and third columns.

Comment: there is no typo, formula is good