# Prove that the determinant of this matrix is equal to $\displaystyle \prod_{\alpha^n=1} (x_o+\alpha x_1+\alpha^2x_2+\ldots+\alpha ^{n-1}x_{n-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Prove that $$\det\begin{pmatrix}
x_0 & x_1 &x_2&\ldots&\ldots&x_{n-1} \\
x_{n-1} & x_0 &x_1&\ldots&\ldots&x_{n-2} \\
\vdots &  \ddots&&&&\vdots \\
\vdots &  &\ddots&&&\vdots \\
x_1 & x_2 &x_3&\ldots&\ldots&x_0 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \displaystyle \prod_{\alpha^n=1} (x_o+\alpha x_1+\alpha^2x_2+\ldots+\alpha ^{n-1}x_{n-1})$$

---

For each$j(2\leq j\leq n)$ I added all the rows times $\alpha^{j-1}$ to the first row, then the elements of $i$th column first row is now $$\alpha^{i-1}(x_0+\alpha x_1+\alpha^2 x_2+\ldots+\alpha^{n-1}x_{n-1})$$

It's quite similar to right hand side, but I could not find out how to proceed from here.

Comment: Well, assuming that
$$x_0+\alpha x_1+\alpha^2 x_2+\ldots+\alpha^{n-1}x_{n-1} = 0$$
(for some $\alpha^n = 1$), your matrix resulting from applying the row operations has a zero row, hence is singular.

Since rank is preserved by row operations, this shows your original matrix is singular, and hence has determinant 0.

I think this means that this polynomial divides the determinant (as a homogeneous polynomial in the $x_i$).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770117/determinant-of-circulant-matrix

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* multiply this matrix by $$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
\zeta_1 & \zeta_2 & \cdots & \zeta_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\zeta_1^{n-1} & \zeta_2^{n-1} & \cdots & \zeta_n^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}$$

Then you will have:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
f(\zeta_1) & f(\zeta_2) & \cdots & f(\zeta_n) \\
\zeta_1f(\zeta_1) & \zeta_2f(\zeta_2) & \cdots & \zeta_nf(\zeta_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\zeta_1^{n-1}f(\zeta_1) & \zeta_2^{n-1}f(\zeta_2) & \cdots & \zeta_n^{n-1}f(\zeta_n)
\end{vmatrix}$$ where $f(\zeta) = \sum x_i \zeta^i$